# XXE prevention via WSDLReader

Tags: wsdl, xxe

I'm using WSDLReader.readWSDL() to create a Wsdl Definition.
I want to know if there is a flag available in javax.wsdl.WSDLReader to check for XXE attack in the WSDL ?

Answer (score 0):

In Java you need to explicitly turn it off. Please try the featured in below link to turn it off
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XMLReader

Adding the code related to the flags to be turned off from the link provided above:

```
XMLReader spf = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd",false);
```

Comment: When posting a solution from a outside source please try to include the related code into your answer also as that link can disappear in the future.